# DotNetNuke 5 - How do I dynamically create a Page, select a Skin, and assign Modules to it?

Tags: .net, asp.net, dotnetnuke

In DNN 5, I need to:

1. Dynamically create a page (programmatically)
2. select a skin
3. assign modules to the page

How do I do this?

Thanks

Comment: You might describe what you are trying to do, not tell others how to do it. Can you create a sample of the required page using DNN?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Mass Tabs](http://masstabs.codeplex.com/) project on codeplex is doing the page creation portion of what you are looking for.

There is also an article [here](http://kemmis.info/blog/archive/2007/11/07/programmatically-creating-dotnetnuke-pages.aspx).

Comment: Good link. I've confirmed that this works with DNN 5.4, but with a keyword change here or there. Pretty easy to figure out based upon the tutorial in the blog